# $_FILES error - undefined index: image

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

UploadImage.php

```
  define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024 * 50); 

  if ((isset($_POST['MM_insert'])) && ($_POST['MM_insert'] =="uploadImg")) {

    // make sure it's a genuine file upload  
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
      // replace any spaces in original filename with underscores
      $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['image']['name']);
      // ...
    }
  }
```

HTML template:

```
<form action="UploadImage.php" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="uploadImg" id="uploadImg">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="MAX_FILE_SIZE" />
    <label for="image">Upload image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /> 
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
  </p>

  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="uploadImg" />
</form>
```

this gives an error; `undefined index: image in ....... UploadImage.php`
I have given enctype form attribute too...bt it's giving an undefined index eror :(

Comment: Your file size is too big as specified in php.ini file

Comment: try to debug $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] or use isset.

Comment: i used isset and the error no more displaying but no data has inserted into the database...

Comment: isset simply stops the code if not file is present, of course nothing gets inserted! Most probably, as @webtecher said, it exceeds the max file size. Check for the 'error' index being equal to 0, or check if the size is under the treshold

Comment: though i increased the maximum file size it gives the same error as undefined index: image, and how to check on if the error index is equal to 0, actually i'm a newbie in php, thank you!

Comment: i uploaded a 7.16KB image, maximum file size is 50KB in here...?

Answer (score 0):

could you post the whole php please? There's no session_start() in your php code.

edit:

`define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024 * 50);` 
must be value in KB, not MB...

try with

```
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024000 * 50);
```